# Замена и адаптация регулярных выражений парсера для работы с кириллицей

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, кириллица

Есть работающий парсер, который переводит текстовый файл. Вот такого формата:

```
27 may 15:28 Id: 42 #1 Random Text 

(Text header 1) Apple                    15
(Text header 2) Milk          2
(Text header 1) Ice cream                   4
(Text header 3) Pencil            1
(Text header 1) Box                    1
   (Text header 2) Cardboard                 x1
   (Text header 3) White                 x1
   (Text header 1) Cube              x1
(Text header 1) Phone     1
   (Text header 1) Specific text                x1
   (Text header 1) Symbian                x1
```

Вот в такой вид:

```
42;15:28
Apple;15;NOHANDLE;NOHANDLE
Milk;2;NOHANDLE;NOHANDLE
"Ice cream";4;NOHANDLE;NOHANDLE
Pencil;1;NOHANDLE;NOHANDLE
Box;1;"Cardboard, White, Cube";NOHANDLE
Phone;1;"Specific text, Symbian";NOHANDLE
```

Т.е. делает из исходного текстового файла, файл в формате CSV и подставляет в случае нехватки элементов "child" слово NOHANDLE.

Вот код этого **работающего** с английским языком скрипта-парсера:

```
<?php

$data = trim(file_get_contents('inbox_file_utf8_clean.txt'));


$all_lines = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $data);
$date_id_line = array_shift($all_lines);
if(!preg_match('/^\d+\s\w+\s(?<time>\d+:\d+)\sId:\s(?<id>\d+).*/', $date_id_line, $matches)) {
  trigger_error('Failed to match ID and timestamp', E_USER_ERROR);
}
$output_data = array(
  'info' => array(
    'id' => $matches['id'],
    'time' => $matches['time']
  ),
  'data' => array()
);

$all_text_headers = array_values(preg_grep('/^\s*\(/', $all_lines));

// The first "Text header" is a parent.
// Count the number of leading whitespaces to determine other parents
preg_match('/^\x20*/', $all_text_headers[0], $leading_space_matches);
$leading_spaces = $leading_space_matches[0];
$num_leading_spaces = strlen($leading_spaces);
$parent_lead = str_repeat(' ', $num_leading_spaces) . '(';
$parent = NULL;
foreach($all_text_headers as $index => $header_line) {
  list($lead, $item_value) = explode(') ', $header_line);
  list($topic, $topic_count) = array_map('trim',
    preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $item_value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
  );

  $topic_count = (int) $topic_count;

  if($is_parent = ($parent === NULL || strpos($lead, $parent_lead) === 0)) {
    $parent = $topic;
  }

  // This only goes one level deep
  if($is_parent) {
    $output_data['data'][$parent] = array(
      'values' => array(),
      'count' => $topic_count
    );
  } else {
    $output_data['data'][$parent]['values'][] = $topic;
  }
};

$csv_delimiter = ';';

$handle = fopen('output_file.csv', 'wb');

fputcsv($handle, array_values($output_data['info']), $csv_delimiter);

foreach($output_data['data'] as $key => $values) {

  $row = array(
    $key,
    $values['count'],
    implode(', ', $values['values']) ?: 'NOHANDLE',
    'NOHANDLE'
  );
  fputcsv($handle, $row, $csv_delimiter);
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Я пытаюсь скормить этом скрипту файл состоящий целиком из кириллицы:

```
28 май 16:49 Зак: 15 #1 Случайный Текст 

(Гот. Строка) Гречка                    1
   (Гот. Строка) Зелень                  x1
   (Гот. Строка) Подлива                 x1
   (Гот. Строка) Хлеб кусок              x1
(Гот. Строка) Яблоко                    15
(Гот. Строка) Молоко          2
(Гот. Строка) Мёд                   4
(Гот. Строка) Коробка                    1
   (Гот. Строка) Картонная                 x1
   (Гот. Строка) Белая                 x1
   (Гот. Строка) Квадратная              x1
```

И парсер не работает... естественно...

Помогите адаптировать скрипт под кириллицу...

Comment: В каждую функцию `preg` к регулярке добавьте флаг `u`, и все `strlen` замените `mb_strlen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала рекомендую узнать про такой прекрасный сайт
https://regex101.com/

На нём можно вставлять регулярку и постепенно, символ за символом находить нерабочие места или составлять свои достаточно высокой сложности.

Скрипт, кстати, должен работать, а именно вываливать ошибку заложенную в коде "Failed to match ID and timestamp"

Например в первом регулярном выражение не "русифицировано" ID на Зак.
Также там была вторая неприятность \w+
Там же есть справка

> \w+ - matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

То есть нет русских символов. Для примера я заменил русские символы

```
^\d+\s[а-яА-Яё]+\s(?<time>\d+:\d+)\sЗак:\s(?<id>\d+).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/JTDG8M/1

Если надо добавить другие символы, то соответственно надо расширить массив, на необходимые символы, например

```
[а-яА-ЯеЁa-zA-Z0-9_]
```

Далее по коду вроде всё должно работать.

Comment: regex101 уже как давно не работает так как надо.